# Was Jackie Chan In Big Trouble In Little China?

Tags: casting, big-trouble-in-little-china

I was watching [Big Trouble In Little China (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090728/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) again today and during the fight scene in the beginning of the movie. I noticed this guy who [to me] looks exactly like Jackie Chan. I looked through the [list of cast and crew](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090728/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) on IMDB, but didn't see him listed anywhere. I also searched Google and didn't come up with anything conclusive. I did, however, find a question on Yahoo Answers [asking the same thing](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090521112909AAC8mXv), and a commentor confirms it is Jackie Chan, and uses the same snapshot I've posted below, but he offers nothing but his word that it is in-fact Jackie Chan.

- Is this indeed Jackie Chan?
- If not, who is it?
- If it is, why wasn't he listed in the credits?

[image]

Comment: We're watching it now & thought that was him too. They can't possibly have all the actors in the alley fight scene listed, especially if they don't have speaking parts.

Comment: Evidently this guy's nose is not big enough to be Jackie Chan  xD

Comment: It's unlikely that Jackie Chan was in BTiLC. Jackie's IMDB site is VERY thorough listing everything he was associated with over his long career. In 1985 and 1986 he was involved in seven productions, all filmed in China, Hong Kong and Japan, execpt "The Protector" which has some scenes in New York, NY. It is my contention that if Jackie had any part in Carpenter's BTiLC, it would be listed in Jackie's biography, in whatever roles he performed at the time (choreographer, actor, etc.). Since it's not in his biography, I personally do not believe he was part of Big Trouble.

Comment: The guy in the picture does not look like Jackie at all. What is this? all chinese look a like to you? ;)

Answer (score 15):

No, Jackie Chan was not in this film.

This character in your photo is indeed Chang Sing (or at least one of them) but Jackie Chan is not credited as any of them.

The credit list for this role (from IMDb) is as follows:

James Lew - Chang Sing #1
Jim Lau -Chang Sing #2
Kenny Endoso - Chang Sing #3 (as Ken Endoso)
Stuart Quan - Chang Sing #4
Gary Toy - Chang Sing #5
George Cheung - Chang Sing #6
Jimmy Jue - Wounded Chang Sing

Comment: If you could identify which actor (i.e. which Chang Sing) the picture above depicts, then I would accept your answer. Before posting the question, I had already looked up pictures of the credited Chang Sings, but did not feel the character depicted above resembled any of them. I was however unable to find pictures of Gary Toy and Jimmy Jue.

Comment: Oh well. No amount of digging has turned up this actor's identity.

Answer (score 8):

I got it! I was wondering this myself after some site I saw a week ago tried to pass this off as factual trivia. I maybe 2 years too late for this answer but I'm convinced its Jim Lau who is listed as Chang Sing #2.

Here are some other photos of him - comparing them with the one above, I think its definitely his nose:

[image: Jim Lau #1]
<sub>(source: [ma-mags.com](http://ma-mags.com/Mags/IKF80/IKF%201981-12%20Cov.jpg))</sub>
[Jim Lau #2 http://mymoviequotes.com/uploads/movies/actor/thumb/98/985/9857-jim-lau-i.jpg](http://mymoviequotes.com/uploads/movies/actor/thumb/98/985/9857-jim-lau-i.jpg)
[image: Jim Lau #3]
[image: Jim Lau #4]